Инициализация и присвоение значения
int test;

Это объявление переменной
test = 5;

Это ее инициализация
int test2 = 5;

А что это? Тут как бы и объявление и инициализация одновременно. Есть ли для этого отдельное название или нет?
И еще пара вопросов (которые не относятся к верхней части): инициализация это присвоение значения переменной в первый раз, в дальнейшем это просто присвоение, правильно
я понимаю?. можно ли сказать определение вместо присвоения, это же не принципиально? Просто везде вижу разные названия и в голове путаница из-за этого.

Загляните сюда.

@OldSkull спасибо. то есть возможность одновременно объявить и присвоить значение переменной присутствует не во всех языках, а в си шарп она есть. ну это одно из вещей что я понял из прочитанного.

да. К тому же, C# не допускает использование неинициализированных переменных. Например, если объявить переменную int a;, а потом написать if ( a == 5 ), то при сборке возникнет ошибка.

"можно ли сказать определение вместо присвоения" - нет, так как определение это, скорее, объявление.

за то отсутствует ли у C# отдельный набор терминов под это дело - не ручаюсь, но в JavaScript обстановка такая: let myNumbers; - объявление, myNumbers = 123; - инициализация, let myNumbers = 123; - а вот это уже на мой взгляд можно назвать определением (что есть определение, если не полное описание? ). хотя тут и это называют инициализацией. на всякий случай напомню, ссылка ведёт на доки именно по JS, описываемого там механизма поДнятий в указанном в вопросе C# может и не быть).

Не путайтесь, всегда инициализируйте переменную сразу изначальным значением.
int a = 42;

Объявление без инициализации редко требуется, например если инициализация переменной происходит в области видимости, которая недуступна при последующем её использовании.
Например
if (x > 0)
{
    int a = 42;
}
else
{
    int a = 123;
}
Console.WriteLine(a); // ОШИБКА

Здесь поможет объявление заранее
int a;
if (x > 0)
{
    a = 42;
}
else
{
    a = 123;
}
Console.WriteLine(a);

Похожая ситуация с блоками using и try-catch будет вам встречаться в будущем. Во всех остальных случаях объявление переменной заранее не только бессмысленно, но и затрудняет чтение кода. Лучше его избегать.
